React How can I iterate and update state with maximum of 2 objects?
I have a state, which is an object, that consists of
ìd: [{}, {}]
It can only be 2 key/value pairs in my state like
{
  243: [{}, {}, {}, ..],
  123: [{}, {}, ..],
}


The way Im doing it, its not limiting it to max 2 key/val pairs. How can I achieve that?
const App = ({ids}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Record<number, Record[]>>({});
  useEffect(() => {
    const callAPI = async () => {
      ids.forEach(id => {
        const result = await axios.post("example.com", {id});
        setData((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          [id]: result ?? [],
        }));
      })
    }
    callAPI()
  })
}


You can hard-code the keys so you only update those 2, or count the number of keys and stop the update if there are more then 2.

Hi as far as I understand your question I would use a type to specify the ids.
It seems you're using Types already. So defining ids as a Tuple might solve that issue.
With this Type you can enforce that the provided Ids are always exactly two numbers; no more no less.
type Ids = [number, number];
type AppProps = {
  ids: Ids
}

const App = ({ids}: AppProps) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Record<number, Record[]>>({});
  useEffect(() => {
    const callAPI = async () => {
      ids.forEach(id => {
        const result = await axios.post("example.com", {id});
        setData((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          [id]: result ?? [],
        }));
      })
    }
    callAPI()
  })
}

If you want to allow 0-2 ids you can make the numbers optional with "?"
type Ids = [number?, number?]

const value: Ids = [] // valid
const value1: Ids = [2] // valid
const value2: Ids = [2, 3] // valid
const value3: Ids = [2, 3, 4] // invalid

EDIT:
I think you need to clarify some things on a business level before the implementation can be done.
Lets say you to use the type to limit the amount of provided IDs to the callApi function to max 2:
If the current state is empty then it's easy. Just add the IDs and their results to the state. Also if the current state holds 1 Entry and you call callAPI with just 1 ID, then the new ID gets added to the state with its result.
But if you don't want to reset the state every time you do a new call to callAPI (which I would assume based on your spread operator) there are the following cases to clarify on a business level in oder to provide a proper implementation.

Current state holds n Items & you call callAPI with 2 IDs: You obviously need to replace the existing ID and their Values with the new ones since you want max. 2 entries.
Current state holds 2 Items & you call callAPI with 1 IDs: Now  if the provided ID exits in the state then you can simply update its value. BUT if the ID does not exist how do you decide which existing entry to override?

If you can answer that question then you could translate that logic into code. When provided 2 IDs then simply replace the state. When Provided 1 ID then check the current state and either simply add the id and its state or replace one of the existing ids.

Did you generated this with a tool like ChatGPT?

I dont want to update same ids, i want to limit the key value pair to 2

No I copied the Question into a react playground and wrote the additional code by hand.

Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.
0

@DarkBee I did not use ChatGPT or other AI tools. I wrote the answer by hand and also didn't ask any AI tools to provide the text for me. Can you let me know why you think that I did?

Please try this way:
a. Create an array of two promises only.
These promises should only be with respect to the two ids in the array of ids which is the props to the application object.
b. fulfil these two promises. The promise.all utility may be used to fulfil the promises.
c. Update State as an when each promise will fulfil. The state updater function is to define as it takes the previous state value, and its body should append the key/value pairs.
d. Display the keys and values. As each key has an array of objects as its value, there is a nested mapping is required to access the values.
Note : Please note that the API fetch has been mocked here with the setTimeout async method and a hard-coded set of values. This is for brevity of the code
Full listing of the code following the above approach.
App.js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DBdata from './data/data';

function App({ ids }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    // creating an array of promises
    const arrayOfPromises = ids
      .filter((item, index) => index < 2)
      .map(
        (id, index) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve({ [id]: [...DBdata[id]] });
            }, 1000)
          )
      );
    // fulfilling all promises
    (async () => {
      const tempData = await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises);
      // updating the state with a state updater
      tempData.map((item) => setData((prevItem) => ({ ...prevItem, ...item })));
    })();
  }, []);
  return (
    // displaying keys and values
    <>
      {Object.keys(data).map((key) => (
        <li key={key}>
          {key} : values :{' '}
          {data[key].map(
            (i, index) => i.name + (index < data[key].length - 1 ? ', ' : '')
          )}{' '}
        </li>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

index.js
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import DBdata from './data/data';

import App from './App';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App ids={Object.keys(DBdata)} />
  </StrictMode>
);

data.js
const DBdata = {
  243: [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' }],
  123: [{ name: 'aa' }, { name: 'bb' }, { name: 'cc' }, { name: 'dd' }],
  111: [{ name: 'aaa' }, { name: 'bbb' }, { name: 'ccc' }],
  222: [{ name: 'aaaa' }, { name: 'bbbb' }, { name: 'cccc' }],
  333: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
};

export default DBdata;

Test run
Browser display on loading the App

